# Book about a witch who tried to murder entire world population

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in English in 2002 or 2003.
The book had a black cover with some circular symbol in the center, I can't remember the shape that was in the symbol.

In the book, the witch tried to murder every living human on earth, by targeting people one by one. She was able to make a body disappear after the deed was done. That is why she could kill so many without getting caught.

I remember two examples.
One guy was killed when he stayed in a library by himself at night. she found him, killed him, and made the body disappear.

Another woman was killed when she left her house late at night to grab a taxi and meet friends.

Later, she felt more powerful and confident so she targeted small groups as well.

In the end, the witch was caught because she did not know her current targets were being followed by police agents who saw her and captured her.

Comment: Killing the whole population one person at the time!? Not a very efficient evil witch lol... Hope you find the book, good luck!

Comment: Reminds me of a famous local serial killer who allegedly believed that God commanded him to kill everyone in the world and set out to do it one by one with the help of his 13-year-old son.

Comment: Killing people one-by-on you would lose against population growth, which is currently a bit over 80 millions a year (almost 3 per second)!

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf that's why she started targeting couples and groups and got caught.

Comment: Was she something like a very old evil witch who had just woken up, and back when she used to be alive the human population was much smaller? Is that why she was pursuing this strategy?

Comment: No, she wanted that there will be no one else at all. not just to make it thinner.

Comment: I mean to say, did she come from a time when individually killing all humans might have been possible?

Comment: I see. No, she was living in her own time when she got all mental.